# Internet service provider bandwidth vs Azure bandwidth

Tags: azure

Would like to know the difference between Internet service provider bandwidth and Azure bandwidth.

We already pay to Internet service provider for bandwidth usage. So Why should I pay for Azure bandwidth ? Isn't just paying for Internet service provider enough ?

May be a simple question. Appreciate if someone can help understand this.

Comment: Azure has a massive investment in their internet infrastructure (I'd imagine to the tune of 10s of millions) They did that to provide a fast, reliable connection to their global presence of data centres. If you use Azure services you get access to that infrastructure at a very cheap rate.

Comment: Of course you don't have to use any Azure services, so you don't have to pay for any of their bandwidth. You pay for internet provision to your front door. When you go to a  hotel you pay to get internet there, because the internet to your front door dooesn't connect there. If you consume Azure services, there's a bandwidth cost. In a similar way to the shipping costs when you buy from amazon.

Comment: @MichaelB , can you explain difference between Internet service provider bandwidth vs Azure bandwidth , in simple manner ?

Comment: Kindly let  me know why the **down votes** ? Is there any `SE` site to ask this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR;

You pay for internet connectivity from your router, to the internet connection located inside your ISP. Azure doesn't see any of that money. They also pay for a connection to the internet. and they pass that cost on to you.

Imagine an internet where all packets are delivered via a delivery company, such as Fedex. However, all packets can only be delivered to a central sorting office.

If you want your packets you have to pay a delivery company to pick them up from the sorting office and deliver them to your house. (or work, mountain lodge)

Now every company that wants to have an internet presence needs to have a delivery company that sends and receives their data. For the average website, that cost is reasonably trivial.

However, if you run a company like Netflix, that becomes a major part of your investment. Because shunting packets around isn't cheap when you've got a lot of them to shunt. Assorted estimates around the web suggest that Netflix pays between tens and hundreds of millions of dollars for bandwidth.

Netflix pays for its data usage by charging its customers. Remember this is still only shunting packets to the central sorting office (the internet)

Amazon, Google, Azure (and other cloud providers) make money by economies of scale. Netflix exists on Amazon infrastructure, using Amazon servers and Amazon internet connectivity. Amazon, Google, and Azure all decided that instead of paying a delivery company to shunt packets to the sorting office, they'd do it themselves (this includes laying intercontinental undersea fibre)

By doing this, cloud providers get to keep all of the costs associated with transferring data in and out of their data centres.

You appear to be asking why doesn't your delivery company charge include the costs of Azure shipping its data into the internet.

According to [Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/service-provider/visual-networking-index-vni/vni-hyperconnectivity-wp.html), in 2016 96 Exabytes of data were transferred across the public internet.

At some point, somebody has to pay for the traffic on the internet, the current model is that the people who send and receive the data from the internet. That means that you pay for the few GB of data your ISP provides you. and Netflix pay for the hundreds of terabytes they use, via AWS billing.

I am confident that if Netflix could pass on the cost of their data consumption directly on to end user ISP's (whether or not they used Netflix) they would do that.

i'm equally sure that if Azure could simply bill ISPs for the data they use, they would happily do that. I'm equally sure you would be less happy paying your share of that 96 exabytes.

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth refers to data moving in and out of Azure data centers other than those explicitly covered by the Content Delivery Network or ExpressRoute pricing. Inbound Data transfer that is data going into Azure data centres is free and Outbound data Transfers that is data going of Azure Datacentre which would be chargeable depending upon the location and bandwidth used. Bandwidth is billed specifically for outbound transfer. So, essentially you're metered for all data leaving a given region. Refer the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/bandwidth/).

Comment: I think you mean data usage, not bandwidth. Bandwidth is how many bits per second it is possible to use on a link, while data usage is how much data (usually in bytes) that you actually have used on the link.

Comment: @RonMaupin  can you explain difference between Internet service provider bandwidth vs Azure bandwidth , in simple manner ?